# How to add touch gesture to Google VR iOS pod?

Tags: ios, swift, virtual-reality

I am using the Google Cardboard VR pod for adding Virtual Reality to my iOS app. I use the`GVRPanoramaView` to display a 360 photo.

In `viewDidLoad()` I enabled `enableTouchTracking`. But this is only working when swiping horizontal and you have to raise your phone to let this work.

Like the Google VR embed for web, you can pan through the image horizontal and vertically: https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview

Is this also possible with Google VR in iOS? Like above example and what is possible with the embed VR in the Facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible with the Google VR SDK in iOS neither with `GVRPanoramaView`, nor with `GVRCardboardView` or `GVRVideoView` and unfortunately the library is not open source right now.

However, there have been a few attempts at open source ports of the Cardboard SDK, for example: https://github.com/rsanchezsaez/CardboardSDK-iOS

It is possible to modify the CBDSceneKit example there to do what you want, like so:

- Remove the `_cameraNode` property.
- Add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the view controller's view
- Inside the gesture recognizer's callback, modify the `eulerAngles` property of `_cameraControlNode` using the `translationInView:` method on the gesture recognizer.

Something like:

```
- (void)didPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
  CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
  _cameraControlNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(translation.y / 100.0, 0.0, translation.x / 100.0);
}
```

I'm not the author though and I can't make any promises about the overall reliability of that library. I also don't know how easy it would be to get it to work with a panorama photo rather than a SceneKit scene.